# Storing multiple instances on a Singleton?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, python, singleton

[RefactoringGuru](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton/python/example)'s example Singleton in Python has an `_instances` dictionary field

```py
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

I'm wondering why one would use use a collection like dictionaries to store an instance. Isn't the whole point of Singleton that there should only ever be *one* instance at a time, defeating the point of using a dictionary?

I would expect it to be

```py
class Singleton(type):
    _instance = None # <- single instance

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._instance is None:
            cls._instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance
```

What is the reasoning for the former? Is this a Python specific implementation? Are there advantages to being able to store multiple instances on the Singleton?

Comment: It's basically exploiting a language mechanism to alter the default behavior of the constructor, and delegate the storage and retrieval of the created (single) instance to a different object (the metaclass), which in turn uses a dictionary to allow for different types to store their own singleton instances. The metaclass aspect makes it convenient in Python, but it's not otherwise relevant structurally - you could, in principle, have this "other object" in other languages, it would just have to be a singleton (or a global) itself (but this is not necessarily something you'd typically do).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are misrepresenting what the cited author wrote, which was:

```
class SingletonMeta(type):

    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            cls._instances[cls] = instance
        return cls._instances[cls]


class Singleton(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    def some_business_logic(self):
        ...
```

Do we invoke `SingletonMeta()` ?
No.
The author assigns `s1 = Singleton()`, and similarly `s2`.
That is quite different.

The singleton pattern has been abstracted away,
so it barely shows up in the class with the business logic.
It takes just the brief mention of `metaclass=SingletonMeta` to pull it in.

Why is a `dict` container necessary?
Because the metaclass supports multiple children classes.
Here are some examples the author did not offer.

```
class WaffleSingleton(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    def make_waffles(self):
        ...

class PancakeSingleton(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    def make_pancakes(self):
        ...
```

Perhaps there is some common cooking implement being managed.
In any event, at this point the metaclass dict would contain three entries.
Note that each of these classes could be placed in a different module,
yet the common import of `SingletonMeta` would be arranging
for them to all update the same `dict`.

---

The approach you mentioned is feasible.
It's just more copy-n-paste boilerplate in each class, staring you in the face.
The goal of the
[metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses)
approach was to be minimally intrusive,
so engineers can focus instead on the business logic.